# Zurb-Foundation: sub-nav background color

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

How can i change sub-nav background color? I can not find any corresponding variable in [Sass variables list](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/subnav.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not present in .settings.scss. You can do:

```
.sub-nav {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This section name is Magellan. See variabe $magellan-bg